# Can I map some key combination to the suspend function (it should also work for waking up the machine from the suspended state)?

Tags: suspend

I'm using an external keyboard for my laptop. The keyboard (USB) does not have a suspend button. This means that I have to keep opening my laptop's lid (I don't want to do that very often as I'm also using an external monitor) in order to wake the laptop up from the suspended state.

Can I map some key combination to wake the laptop up from the suspended state?

Note that it may not be as trivial as it seems, as it has to work for waking the laptop up and likely Gnome shortcuts and similar things will not work. Likely it has to be some lower level thing, but what (if at all possible)?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the computer suspends, Ubuntu is no longer running until you resume, so there is no way for Ubuntu to set a keyboard shortcut that will work while the computer is suspended.

Many PC's have an option in the BIOS to trigger a resume from suspend if *any* key is pressed. That may be your best bet, combined with setting a specific shortcut inside Ubuntu for suspending.

Comment: I understand. So I assume external keyboards that have a suspend button on them are sending a "hardcoded" signal that the hardware in a laptop can understand (so no involvment from the software/OS).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the keyboard is external or not. I've never heard of any feature that maps *specific* keys while a computer is suspended. The only feature I've seen is what I've described above: wake-up on *any* key press.